# Phonegap - cannot scroll vertically on Android Kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: cordova, scroll, android-4.4-kitkat

We made an Android app using Phonegap, that app was working fine in all Android versions but recently launched Android version Kitkat 4.4 and its vertical scrolling is not working in all UI-pages.

I did a lot of research on the web, read Android 4.4 docs, and somewhere I found that Android 4.4 remove old webkit and use Chrome as a default browser but haven't find any proper solution.

Kitkat doesn't use webKit anymore, it uses Chromium so there are some inconsistencies.

The weird thing is that on Phonegap build it is working, on local build (Cordova 3.5 CLI) the vertical scroll bar doesn't work.

Comment: What are you using for vertical scroll? Is it a JS library or CSS properties? can you add some code to the question?

Comment: i am using simply cordova + jquery mobile. no additional plugins for scrolling. it is working fine on all platforms, except this verions of android.

Comment: did someone find a solution?